# Find mean of list in F#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to find the average of a list

Here's what I have so far

```
let rec avg aList =
    match aList with
    | head::tail -> head+avg(tail)
    | [] -> 0
```

This obtains the sum. I've tried head+avg(tail)/aList.Length, but it gives me an incorrect result as I don't know exactly what that's doing

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: why not to do something like that: `myList |> List.average`
i.e. `[1.0..5.0] |> List.average` produces `3.0` as a result.

Comment: I guess you also wanna handle empty lists as well: `match myList with | [] -> 0.0 | _ -> myList |> List.average`

Answer (score 3):

For an average, you'd want two things, the sum and the number of items. Using `List.length` would mean traversing the list again.
We can do those two things at the same time - by using a tuple.

This operation is known as folding (or sometimes aggregation). We apply the folding function, gathering our state as we traverse the list without mutating anything.

```
let avg aList =
    let rec accumulate (sum, count) list =
        match list with
        | head::tail -> accumulate (sum + head, count + 1) tail
        | [] -> (sum, count)
    let sum, count = accumulate (0, 0) aList
    let average = sum / count
    average
```

You can generalize this using `fold`.

```
let avg aList =        
    let sum, count = 
        List.fold (fun (sum, count) current -> (sum + current, count + 1)) (0,0) aList
    let average = sum / count
    average
```

The generic math version:

```
let inline avg (list: 'a list) =        
    let rec accumulate (sum, count) list =
           match list with
           | head::tail -> accumulate (Checked.(+) sum head, count + 1) tail
           | [] -> (sum, count)
    let sum, count = accumulate (LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero<'a>, 0) list
    let average = LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt sum count
    average
```

Comment: This is working with `int` maths. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Oh, now I see that I was cheating using List.length 

Comment: @Enigmativity No, it gets constrained to the type of zero. It hopefully illustrates the concept of folding. I added a generic math version which is a lot more ugly.

Comment: @FilipeCarvalho I see your cheating, and one up you with `let inline avg list = List.average list` ;)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way of doing this is using the [average](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.average%5B%5Et%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) high-order function from the [List module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.list-module-%5Bfsharp%5D). You can do this on a single line with

```
let myAverage = aList |> List.average
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let avg aList =
    let rec sum = function
        | head :: tail -> head + (sum tail)
        | [] -> 0.
    sum aList / (aList |> List.length |> float)

let res = avg [ 2.; 4.; 6. ]
printfn "%A" res
```

I'm not sure this is the best way to do it tho.